# Python: "pip install gmpy" on Windows 10 returns "cl.exe' failed with exit status 2"

Tags: python, pip, cl, cl.exe, gmpy

I've installed Pyhton 3.7 on Windows10 and when I run `pip install gmpy` the console return me this error:

```
Collecting gmpy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/26/37/2184c13cee81e1dbeaebbb13570195247e73ab2138a3db0c9d2c5347e372/gmpy-1.17.zip
Building wheels for collected packages: gmpy
  Building wheel for gmpy (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\franc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-du1j9u7s\\gmpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\franc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-du1j9u7s\\gmpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-nz4_kuat' --python-tag cp37
       cwd: C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-du1j9u7s\gmpy\
  Complete output (12 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'gmpy' extension
  creating build
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Ic:\python37\include -Ic:\python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.7.2\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/gmpy.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/gmpy.obj
  gmpy.c
  C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-du1j9u7s\gmpy\src\gmpy.h(30): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gmp.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.23.28105\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for gmpy
  Running setup.py clean for gmpy
Failed to build gmpy
Installing collected packages: gmpy
    Running setup.py install for gmpy ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\franc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-du1j9u7s\\gmpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\franc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-du1j9u7s\\gmpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-q7ltkyyx\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-du1j9u7s\gmpy\
    Complete output (12 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'gmpy' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Ic:\python37\include -Ic:\python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.7.2\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/gmpy.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/gmpy.obj
    gmpy.c
    C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-du1j9u7s\gmpy\src\gmpy.h(30): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gmp.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.23.28105\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\franc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-du1j9u7s\\gmpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\franc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-du1j9u7s\\gmpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-q7ltkyyx\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

The error is in this line:

```
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.23.28105\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Basically it means that Python needs `cl.exe` and it expect it at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\Hostx86\x64
```

No problem, I go to the Environment Variable and i add that path both for my user and for the system:

[image]

Then I check if `cl.exe` is successfully in the path by typing `cl` in the terminal and it works:

[image]

But when I run again `pip install gmpy` I have the same error.

**EDIT:** I also tried with `pip install gmpy2` and I receive the same error.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: `gmpy` looks dead. Try `pip install gmpy2` maybe? https://pypi.org/project/gmpy2/

Comment: same problem with gmpy2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the actual problem is that you are missing some header file `gmp.h`:

```
C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-du1j9u7s\gmpy\src\gmpy.h(30): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gmp.h': No such file or directory
```

I suggest you try [`gmpy2`](https://pypi.org/project/gmpy2/), which is a newer version. It has wheels for Windows on PyPI but they are for older versions of Python unfortunately. Pre-built wheels for more recent Python versions are available [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gmpy). The files are named after the Python version (e.g. `cp37` for CPython 3.7) and architecture (e.g. `amd64` for 64-bit)

A wheel can be installed like so:

```
pip install gmpy2‑2.0.8‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: I have the same problem with gmpy2

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani I've updated the answer to link to wheels built for more recent Python versions.